# Installation of Libasound-2 dev

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, graphics

Hello guys I am in pop os and I tried installing libasound-2 dev package from https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/21.04/ubuntu-main-amd64/libasound2-dev_1.2.4-1.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb.html
but after trying to install it there comes a error saying  :

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libasound2-dev: Depends: libasound2 (= 1.2.4-1.1ubuntu2)

P.S : I was trying to install graphics.h but it showed error in libsound2-dev package and libpulse where libpulse is solved. Due to which I could not install SDL.

Comment: Try installing the `libasound2` first and then its development package `libasound2-dev`.  
`sudo apt install libasound2 && sudo apt install libasound2-dev`

Comment: I did the same but it is showing same problem:


The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libasound2-dev : Depends: libasound2 (= 1.2.4-1.1ubuntu3)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Please update your Question.

Comment: There are plenty of resources online that you can refer and spend some time reading it to resolve your issue https://itsfoss.com/held-broken-packages-error/ and https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages

Comment: I am voting to close this question as it does not meet the SO question standard, it belongs to different stack exchange site.

Comment: i searched the package libasound2-dev it shows but when i try to install it shows the same error, I went through all the both links not helping.